# Closing-option redundancies and/or errors on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

In looking to mark questions as "*Needs more details or clarity*", which would suffice to say the matter is *on-topic*, but needs more info, I noticed a few votes recently have been going towards "*Off Topic because... seeking debugging help but needs more details*" which does not sound like Off-topic at all. The description further amplifies that this seems inappropriate for "Off-topic" options.

Are closing-options still being revisited, and if so, is this redundancy/error going to be resolved?

**Images of Closing options:**

Base Closing pop-up:

> [image]

Off-topic options:

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question topicality on the site is not solely defined by subject matter (what the question is about), but a about question form or type of question.

Opinion-based questions, for example, are off-topic even if the opinions being asked about are about subject matters that are on-topic on the site.

Same thing with a question that it's too unclear to be unequivocally answered, or a question that simply does not provide all the necessary information for another user to be able to answer (e.g. lacks the necessary code to reproduce the problem, for debugging questions).

I believe *"Off-topic"* is perfectly acceptable label to encompass this type of questions.

Comment: With the understanding of off-topic being more than purely subject matter where on-topic would be objective questions (non-discussion), my inquiry is specific to what appears to be a duplication of `Needs details or clarity` also appearing as an Off-topic option.  If the Off-topic option were to explicitly state "...as this is a discussion piece or is not an objective question targeting a single response" I would be all on board.  Do you feel my interpretation an inappropriate assessment of the two mentioned Closing-options?

Comment: There is overlap between the different close reasons. Even more so with the current version of the reasons. But the distinction serves so users can pick the a description that better describes their understanding on why the question should be closed. Yes, you could choose "needs details" for a question that lacks code, and in that "seeks debugging" would be redundant, but there are many questions that lack details and are yet they are not questions that are seeking debugging help.

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up, and I can understand the points you make.  Specific to the question in my post, "Are closing-options still being revisited"?  I'd be quite happy to wrap this question up as answered if that is known.

Comment: They have been changed quite recently. I imagine reviewing it's never "done", and in the same way they were changed in the past they could be changed in the future.

Comment: After reading all comments it's still not clear to me, if I should flag a question thats asks for help with an error but fails to provide A) Code or B) The error or C) Both as either `Off-Topic: seeks debugging advice` or `Needs Details or Clarity`. Could me choosing `Off-Topic: seeks debugging advice` while other reviews decided for `Needs Details or Clarity` result in a disputed flag?

Comment: No @Björn, it's not particularly important which option you choose. There is overlap in close reasons. Just choose the one that you think describes the issue the best. Sometimes a question can be closed for more than one reason.